# Remediation of Apache Log4j Security Vulnerabilities for Flowable

Tags: log4j, flowable

I just wanted to know that is there any remediation/solution documented step of Apache Log4j Security Vulnerabilities for Flowable, please let us know if any new release has addressed the Apache Log4j Security Vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flowable has fixed the issue in a release https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/releases/tag/flowable-6.7.2